# How to Clear Inactive Memories in ios

Tags: iphone, memory

You have likely seen the many app which display information related to memory like active memory, inactive memory and free memory, i have found out all above information related to memory. 
  My question is how to clear memory?

Comment: clear inactive memory? inactive? but why?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate a lot of memory in the app, until iOS issue you the low-memory warning message. [iOS programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html) describes how to observe low-memory warning in "Observe Low-Memory Warnings" section.

In iOS, when memory usage of active application increase, the operating system tends to terminate suspended applications to help alleviate the memory shortage issue as described in "Use Memory Efficiently" section of the same document above. So if you keep allocating memory until the point that you get warned by iOS, it is very likely that other suspended application that had occupied the memory should be terminated already.